# How do exclude double quota from text by using Java regexp?

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace text patterned like

```
test 1 | test "2" | test 3
```

to

```
test 1 | test 2 | test 3
```

I have checked regex patterns like `([^"]*) or (?>([^"]))` but didn't work. I basically use [this](http://myregexp.com/) site to verify the result.

Any hint much appreciated!

Thanks,
Seymur

Comment: you mean `input = input.replace("\"", "");`

Comment: Why must it be regexp?

Comment: or `input = input.replaceAll("\"(\\d+)\"", "$1");`

Comment: I need just to have a valid regexp which can "produce" the desired text from source text. Requirement is to use ONLY regexp, not Java methods

Comment: may be requirement is wrong, because i didn't find anything about regex that it can excerpt whole text without including double quotas.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:-

```
String input =  "test 1 | test \"2\" | test 3";
String output = input.replaceAll("\"(\\d+)\"", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match `"`, capture one or more digits `(\d+)` in a capturing group and then match again `"`.

Then in the replacement use captured group 1. `$1`

[`"(\d+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/6yBVAp/1)

In Java: `String regex = "\"(\\d+)\"";`

[Demo Java](http://rextester.com/EOY72353)